# Objective C iPad - Memory problems using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I have a memory problem with this loop. I use ARC, so normally I cannot release any objects. But during this loop process, the memory grow up and the iPad crash after a moment (without warning and error).

Is there a solution to solve this problem? I don't understand why the memory grow up?

Thank you for your help.

```
_rawdatalocal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RAWDATA"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];    

for(int j = 1; j <[array count];j++)
        {
            NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[array objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];

            if([values count] == 12)
            {
            _rawdatalocal.accX = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.accY = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.accZ = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:3] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.gyrX = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:4] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.gyrY = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:5] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.gyrZ = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:6] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.magX = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:7] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.magY = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:8] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.magZ = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:9] intValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.temperature = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:[[values objectAtIndex:10] floatValue]];
                _rawdatalocal.temps = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[values objectAtIndex:11] intValue]];

        }
```

PS : Normally the line below is in the loop

```
_rawdatalocal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RAWDATA"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Do you really need to use NSNumber ? If you are not trying to convert anything in your code, stick with a simple int or long. It will use less memory and be faster to initialize. I don't know how many loops you have, but it can be significant if you say that it creates memory crashes. Profile your app and tell us about the memory space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an autorelease pool inside your loop to avoid memory spikes. In arc, you need to put your autorelease polls as following:

```
@autorelease{

}
```

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)